# Casting Object[] to custom Item[]

Tags: android, listview, casting, arraylist

I have my ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

It is then populated with Items.
Later on, I want to access the items attributes in a loop to get data but

```
Item[] itemArr = (Item[]) itemList.toArray();
```

This gives me error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.raynemartin.SAAndroidAppCompetition.Item[]
```

If this is destined to fail, how else can I access attributes of Items?
The Items are in an ArrayList so they can populate and android ListView. Now I want to sort the ArrayList, but need to access the .getRating() method of my Item class.

```
Item[] itemArr= (Item[])itemList.toArray();

    for(int i =0;i<itemArr.length;i++){
            for(int j=i;i<itemArr.length;j++){
                if(itemArr[j].getRating()>itemArr[i].getRating()){
                        Item temp = itemArr[j];
                        itemArr[j] = itemArr[i];
                        itemArr[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT - here is item class code

```
public class Item {

    private String title;
    private String category;
    private String downloads;
    private double rating;
    private Bitmap icon;

    public Item(String title, String category, String downloads,double rating,Bitmap icon) {
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
        this.downloads = downloads;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDownloads() {
        return downloads;
    }

    public void setDownloads(String downloads) {
        this.downloads = downloads;
    }

    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `Item` class code.http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/. check this

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but worth changing anyway:  change ArrayList<Item> to List<Item>.

Comment: Try Item[] itemArr = itemList.toArray(new Item[itemList.size()]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort you can try the below.

In your Item class implement toString

```
public String toString()
{
    return String.valueOf(rating);
}
```

Implement a Comparator

```
 class SortingRating implements Comparator<Item>
{

        @Override
        public int compare(Item arg0, Item arg1) {
            if (arg0.getRating() < arg1.getRating()) return -1;
            if (arg0.getRating() > arg1.getRating()) return 1;
            return 0;
    }

}
```

Then sort your list

```
   Collections.sort(itemList, new SortingRating());
```

Example : Correct me if i am wrong.

```
public class MainClass {
    static ArrayList<Item> aa = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Item i1 = new Item("soap","sales","yes",4.0);
        aa.add(i1);
        Item i2 = new Item("soap","sales","yes",5.2);
        aa.add(i2);
        Item i3 = new Item("soap","sales","yes",3.8);
        aa.add(i3);
        Item i4 = new Item("soap","sales","yes",5.1);
        aa.add(i4);

         Collections.sort(aa, new SortingRating());
         for(int i=0;i<aa.size();i++)
         {
         System.out.println("Title  : " +aa.get(i).getTitle()+"--"+"Category : "+aa.get(i).getCategory()+"--"+"Downlaods : "+aa.get(i).getDownloads()+"--"+"Rating : "+aa.get(i).getRating());
         }

    }
}
class SortingRating implements Comparator<Item>
{

        @Override
        public int compare(Item arg0, Item arg1) {
            if (arg0.getRating() < arg1.getRating()) return -1;
            if (arg0.getRating() > arg1.getRating()) return 1;
            return 0;
        }   
}
```

Item class. Left out Bitmap icon

```
public class Item  {

    private String title;
    private String category;
    private String downloads;
    private double rating;


    public Item(String title, String category, String downloads,double rating) {
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
        this.downloads = downloads;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(rating);
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDownloads() {
        return downloads;
    }

    public void setDownloads(String downloads) {
        this.downloads = downloads;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Title  : soap--Category : sales--Downlaods : yes--Rating : 3.8
Title  : soap--Category : sales--Downlaods : yes--Rating : 4.0
Title  : soap--Category : sales--Downlaods : yes--Rating : 5.1
Title  : soap--Category : sales--Downlaods : yes--Rating : 5.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the class **Item** implement the interface [Comparable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html) and use

```
Collections.sort(itemList);
```

to sort your collection. So you don't have to construct an array and sort it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to access the elements as an array you would be better using

```
itemList.toArray(new Item[0]);
```

or

```
itemList.toArray(new Item[itemList.size()]);
```

as this will give you an array of type Item rather than an array of object. There is lots of discussion on this issue else where on the web.

Comment: Thanks, this is a easy to use solution